# How does spot-futures arbitrage work in the gold market?

Tags: trading, futures, gold, commodities, arbitrage

At the time of writing:

- According to [Kitco](http://www.kitco.com/charts/livegold.html), the **spot** price for gold is about $1240 per ounce.
- According to [CME Group](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/precious/gold.html), **futures** contracts are above that price for many months ahead.

Why couldn't I buy an ounce of gold at the current spot price of $1240 and sell a futures contract for August 2014 at $1256, hold it until it expires, and guarantee myself a 16 dollar profit?

Am I missing something here? Why don't more people do this?

Comment: Have you looked to see the contract size for the future you would sell? These things are priced per oz, but trade in quantities far higher.

Comment: Right, I believe each contract is equivalent to 100 Troy Ounces, so that's how much I'd have by at market value. I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Have you considered commissions as well?

Answer (score 9):

You're missing the [cost-of-carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_carry) aspect:

> The cost of carry or carrying charge is the cost of storing a physical commodity, such as grain or metals, over a period of time. The carrying charge includes insurance, storage and interest on the invested funds as well as other incidental costs. In interest rate futures markets, it refers to the differential between the yield on a cash instrument and the cost of the funds necessary to buy the instrument.

So in a nutshell, you'd have to store the gold (safely), invest your money *now*, i.e. you're missing out on interests the money could have earned until the futures delivery date.  Well and on top of that you need to get the gold shipped to London or wherever the agreed delivery place is.

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention that of course there *are* arbitrageurs that make sure the futures and spot market prices don't diverge.

So the idea isn't that bad as I might have made it sound but being in the arbitrage business myself I should disclaim that profits are small and arbitraging is highly automated, so before *you* spot a $1 profit somewhere between any two contracts, you can be quite sure it's been taken by an arbitrageur already.

Comment: +1 - Plus you are risking all that for a measly 1.3% return over 13 months.

Comment: Since I've posted this Gold spot price has dropped to 1233 but the futures for August 2014 are still at 1256, has the future market not responded to the change just yet?

Comment: It has, the current quotes are 1242.40 for 4 v 1 @ 1242.60, there has been no trade though, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I'm also not understanding the whole "interest on the invested funds" bit. What exactly is this interest referring to? Aren't I just buying gold at the spot price (1233 at this moment), selling a futures contract simultaneously, and then collecting the 1256 on August 2014? I don't understand the interest part.

Comment: Buying a future today is just a promise, no money or goods are exchanged until maturity (well apart from daily settlement cash flows).  You have to get your wallet out in 13 months, so you can invest your cash somewhere else, e.g. put it into a savings account and earn interest.  The spot buyer has got to pay today, their money is exchanged immediately for gold and hence won't get them any interest.

Comment: hroptatyr, I'm reading off the CME link posted above, and it says the last price is 1256. Do you think it just says that because there has not been a trade on it yet? I don't have a live platform to look at this at the moment.

Comment: Oh, so because I'm buying it at spot, and selling the futures contract, I am losing out on the interest I could have earned had I not bought the spot gold right now. Is that correct? What interest rate is used in these equations?

Comment: The price is 1256.5 *a*, that is an **ask** quote, not a trade; see http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/about-quotes.html

Comment: Re the interest, yes that's exactly correct.  You'd use the one you can realise.  Because after all, if you want to decide if there is an arbitrage you'd consider alternative investments *you* could have done instead.  On the same note, not everyone's insurance or shipping costs are the same, so you'd throw the *actual* costs for *you* into the equation.

Comment: Is it possible you can show me a numerical example with the current futures prices for gold (you can pick the month) and the spot price? I'd like to see how they are equal.

Comment: Take Aug13 v Aug14 settlements: 1251.9 v 1259.3, that's 1251.9 + 0.49% (= USD-LIBOR-1Y - 20bp) + $99 storage/insurance + $25 shipping + $3 trading costs = 1259.30431  (Note: the contract size is 100, so divide dollar amounts by 100).

Comment: Why is 20bp subtracted from the rate?

Comment: @Jon: interest rate spread, LIBOR is a benchmark or so to speak a mid-point of an interest rate swap, however you'd have to "sell" (lend) it for the current bid, which is typically below the benchmark, or "buy money" (aka borrow) at the current ask which is above it

Answer (score 2):

As proposed:

Buy 100 oz of gold at $1240 spot = -$124,000

Sell 1 Aug 2014 Future for $1256 = $125,600

Profit $1,600

Alternative Risk-Free Investment:

1 year CD @ 1% would earn $1240 on $124,000 investment.
Rate from ads on www.bankrate.com

"Real" Profit
All you are really being paid for this trade is the difference between the 
profit $1,600 and the opportunity for $1240 in risk free earnings.  That's only $360 or around 0.3%/year.

Pitfalls of trying to do this:

1. Many retail futures brokers are set up for speculative traders and do not want to deal with customers selling contracts against delivery, or buying for delivery.
2. If you are a trader you have to keep margin money on deposit.  This can be a T-note at some brokerages, but currently T-notes pay almost 0%.
3. If the price of gold rises and you are short a future in gold, then you need to deposit more margin money.  If gold went back up to $1500/oz, that could be $24,400.  If you need to borrow this money, the interest will eat into a very slim profit margin over the risk free rate.
4. Since you can't deliver, the trades have to be reversed.  Although futures trades have cheap commissions ~$5/trade, the bid/ask spread, even at 1 grid, is not so minimal.  Also there is often noisy jitter in the price.  The spot market in physical gold may have a higher bid/ask spread.
5. You might be able to eliminate some of these issues by trading as a hedger or for delivery.  Good luck finding a broker to let you do this... but the issue here for gold is that you'd need to trade in depository receipts for gold that is acceptable for delivery, instead of trading physical gold.  To deliver physical gold it would likely have to be tested and certified, which costs money. By the time you've researched this, you'll either discover some more costs associated with it or could have spent your time making more money elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did this and there were no other costs or risks involved, you might actually make a loss in **real terms** due to inflation.

If the purchasing power of $1240 today is greater than the purchasing power of $1256, 13 months in the future, that means you are making a loss with your arbitrage. It's not a get-rich-scheme even if it works.

Comment: Inflation is not a factor here - the net profit is $16 regardless of any inflationary activity. The PP of that $16 would be less due to inflation, but inflation would not reduce the absolute return. There might be _other_ investments that are better during high inflation, but it's not the main problem here.